# Benchmarking AWS Cloudfront

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Has anyone benchmarked the effect of using AWS/Cloudfront as a CDN on response times?

Comment: What do you want to know? Please specific which benchmark you want to know? Which region? Which content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Here is for you quick reference, by simply requesting the S3, Cloud front and my own hosting server. I get this result.

This client is in Malaysia.

2. S3 East Region 810ms.
3. CloudFront miss from CloudFront 1.61s
4. CloudFront hit from CloudFront 83ms
5. Own Hosting server in Hong Kong 4.72s

You should better to do you benchmark yourself. I would recommend you to use http://blitz.io/ . It give you a complete benchmark in your situation.

[image]

Comment: CloudFront doesn't have a server in Malaysia. If the client come from Japan/Hong Kong, the response time can be reduced to around 20ms in my case

Comment: blitz.io is a pretty solid abstraction of Apache Benchmark, thanks.